# How can you take the dual of a category whose objects are Sets?

Tags: category-theory

Let's say I have a category with two objects

```
A {1, 2}
B {3}
```

I have the following morphisms

```
ida A->A, 1->1, 2->2
idb B->B, 3->3
f A->B 1->3, 2->3
```

How can I take the dual category? If I flip the arrows, where does f point? Does it become two arrows? Do you choose?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Viewed as an arrow of the original category, $f$ has type $A \rightarrow B$. Hence viewed as an arrow of the dual category, $f$ has type $B \rightarrow A$. Make sense?

Comment: But if your category is Set, then what is the interpretation of the arrows in C^op? In C they are functions and things like equalizers rest on being able to compare functions. How does that work in C^op?

Comment: @AQuestionAsker, $f$ is still a function. Its still $f$. Nothing about $f$ has changed. Viewed as an arrow of $\mathbf{Set}$, the domain of $f$ is still $A$. However, viewed as an arrow of the category that is dual to the one that is defined in your question, the domain of $f$ is $B$.

Comment: What is the codomain of f in the dual category, though? Or do you mean that in the dual category, B->A means in fact that in set it is a function with A as the domain and B as the codomain, but our notation has changed?

Comment: @AQuestionAsker, $A$.

Comment: @AQuestionAsker, try to remember that $\mathrm{dom}(f)$ is a shorthand. There's a difference between $\mathrm{dom}_\mathbf{Set}(f)$ and $\mathrm{dom}_{\mathbf{C}}(f)$ and $\mathrm{dom}_{\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}(f).$

Comment: I think where I get confused is that f is two things. One is a function on a set. The other is a morphisms in a category. So in the dual category, does anything about the function itself change, or just the notation?

Comment: @AQuestionAsker, nothing about the function changes. Only our viewpoint on the function has changed. If we're viewing $f$ as an arrow of $\mathbf{C}$, then by the domain of $f$, we implicitly mean $\mathrm{dom}_\mathbf{C}(f)$. If we're viewing $f$ as an arrow of $\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$, then by the domain of $f$, we implicitly mean $\mathrm{dom}_{\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}(f)$, which equals $\mathrm{cod}_\mathbf{C}(f).$

Answer (score 2):

You get a category with two objects, $A$, and $B$, and three morphisms:

${\rm id}_A : A \to A$, ${\rm id}_B : B \to B$, and $\hat{f} : B \to A$.

Both the original category that you describe and this category are isomorphic to the category $\mathbf{2}$, with two objects, their identities, and a morphism between them.

Comment: This makes sense, but then how is it that some property of C necessarily translates? Equalizers for example only make sense if your morphisms have some extra meaning (like in Set), so when you do C^op of the category Set, how can you make sense of the properties you get for free?

Comment: No, equalizers make sense in *any category* (at most some of them don't exist), no 'extra meaning' is needed whatever you mean by that.